# Type inference not working as expected for generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For a function I'd like to provide a data source in a generic way, e.g. either as url `string` or a callback that returns a `Promise<string>`

```
const processUrl = async (url: string | (() => Promise<string>)) => {
    //Retrieve url...
    const urlData = typeof url === "function" ? await url() : url;
    //Proceed...
};
```

This works, however I have problems generalizing this approach using a generic

```
type DataInput<T> = T | (() => Promise<T>);

const retrieveDataInput_Impl1 = <T, DataInputType extends DataInput<T>>(t: DataInputType): Promise<T> => typeof t === "function" ? t() : t;
//No error, but return type is always unknown

const retrieveDataInput_Impl2 = <T extends any>(t: DataInput<T>): Promise<T> => typeof t === "function" ? t() : t;
//Shows the following error for t(): This expression is not callable. Not all constituents of type '(() => Promise<T>) | (T & Function)' are callable. Type 'T & Function' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

const b1 = await retrieveDataInput_Impl1("a"); // type of b1 is unknown, getDataInput1 is showing no error
const b2 = await retrieveDataInput_Impl2("a"); // type of b2 is string, but getDataInput2 is showing an error
```

How could this functionality be implemented with full type safety?

Comment: This functionality cannot be implemented with full type safety because `T` could well be a function type itself. I recommend simply writing two functions, one of which takes a `T`, one of which takes a `() => Promise<T>`, and the caller (who should know whether or not they have a value, or a function returning `Promise`) is expected to call the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disallowing `T` to be a function fixes the ambiguity. You should also make the function `async` so it still returns a Promise when the argument is returned directly.

```
type DataInput<T> = T extends Function ? never : (() => Promise<T>) | T;
const retrieveDataInput_Impl3 = async <T>(t: DataInput<T>): Promise<T> => typeof t === "function" ? t() : t;

retrieveDataInput_Impl3('foo') // => Promise<"foo">
retrieveDataInput_Impl3({ key: 'value' }) // => Promise<{ key: string }>
retrieveDataInput_Impl3(async () => 123) // => Promise<number>
retrieveDataInput_Impl3(async () => {}) // => Promise<void>
retrieveDataInput_Impl3(() => {}) // => Error
```

This solution doesn't seem to accept `T` of type `boolean` though, because of some other issue.

### Update

Since it doesn't matter whether an async function returns a value or a Promise of the value, you might as well allow passing any function and fix your error with a simple type assertion.

```
type DataInput<T> = (() => Promise<T>) | (() => T) | T;
const retrieveDataInput_Impl3 = async <T,>(t: DataInput<T>): Promise<T> =>
  typeof t === "function" ? (t as Function)() : t;

retrieveDataInput_Impl3(() => 42) // => Promise<number)>
retrieveDataInput_Impl3(async () => Promise.resolve(42)) // => Promise<number>
retrieveDataInput_Impl3(() => () => 42) // => Promise<() => number)>
```

Comment: Nice, btw. unless you're using JSX, you can get rid of that comma in `<T,>`.